# What is the best way to check if array has values other than null in php?

Tags: php

In PHP `empty([null, null, null])` will obviously return `false`.

What is the best way from the performance point of view to detect that an array contains only null values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Performance testing of the answers so far using this code, first with an array of 1000 null values, then an array with 999 null values and one (random) non-null value:

```
$array = array_fill(0, 1000, null);
$elapsed = array();
foreach (array('Nick1', 'Nick2', 'Eddie', 'Vivek') as $func) {
    $start = explode(' ', microtime());
    for ($i = 0; $i < 10000; $i++) $func($array);
    $elapsed[$func] = elapsed_time($start);
}
```

In the tables, Nick1 = `array_reduce`, Nick2 = `count(array_filter)`, Vivek = `for` (aka Nick3).

Results (all null array):

```
Function    Elapsed Time    Delta
Vivek       0.654           0%
Nick2       0.886           35%
Nick1       0.964           47%
Eddie       3.122           377%
```

Results (array with 999 null values, 1 random non-null value, different each iteration)

```
Function    Elapsed Time    Delta
Vivek       0.305           0%
Nick2       0.888           191%
Nick1       0.891           192%
Eddie       3.114           921%
```

As can be seen for the all-`null` array, the `for` loop is considerably faster, mainly because it doesn't suffer the overhead of a function call for each value. For the array with one non-`null` value, it's even faster as it can break as soon as it finds a non-`null` value.

Leave a comment if you want your answer to be added to the test...

Comment: I was thinking the same as this needs time measurement. My simple code `function isAllNull($array){
    for($i=count($array)-1;$i>=0;--$i){
        if(!is_null($array[$i])) return false;
    }
    return true;
} 
`

Comment: @vivek_23 was just editing that into my answer but I'll put it under your name...

Comment: You can also add it as `Nick3` if you like, to be on fair terms.

Comment: @vivek_23 then it would look like I was rigging the results! :)

Comment: Not really because we both were coincidentally doing the same things. :) [We could also delete our previous comments ;) ]

Answer (score 1):

One option is using [`array_unique`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) to get all unique array values. If there is only one element and that element is null, all elements are null.

```
$unique = array_unique( [null, null, null] );

if ( count( $unique ) === 1 && $unique[0] === null ) {
    //All Null
} else {
    //Not all Null
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a couple of ways to determine that an array only contains null values:

```
$array = array(null, null, null);
echo array_reduce($array, function ($c, $v) { return $c && is_null($v); }, true) ? 'empty' : 'not empty';
echo !count(array_filter($array, function($v) { return !is_null($v); })) ? 'empty' : 'not empty';
```

Output:

```
empty
empty
```

And then of course we have the humble for loop:

```
$c = count($array);
for ($i = 0; $i < $c; $i++) {
    if (!is_null($array[$i])) {
        echo "not empty";
        break;
    }
}
if ($i == $c) echo "empty";
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/PuRTo)

Answer (score 1):

```
$arrayIsNull = ($array = array_unique([null, null, null])) && (next($array) === false && is_null($array[0]));
```